# Fastest way to extract elements from a multi-dimensionnal array at specified array of indices

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an n-D array `A`, with an arbitrary n:

```
a = np.arange(3*4*5*...).reshape((3, 4, 5, ...))
```

...And I have an array of indices (exactly this shape or transposed):

```
ix = np.array([
  [0,1,1,...],
  [0,0,1,...],
  [1,0,1,...],
])
```

What is the fastest way of getting an array of the elements from a at indices from ix ?

(e.g. the fastest way of obtaining :

```
def take_at(a, ix):
  res = np.empty((ix.shape[0],*a.shape[ix.shape[1]:]))
  for i in range(ix.shape[0]):
    res[i,...] = a[(*ix[i],)]
  return res
```

...Using (if possible) only numpy vectorized function / loop / operations ?)

simple copy-pastable example to test : :

```
a = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape((3,4,5))

ix = np.array([
  [0,1,1],
  [0,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
])

def take_at(a, ix):
  res = np.empty((ix.shape[0],*a.shape[ix.shape[1]:]), dtype=a.dtype)
  for i in range(ix.shape[0]):
    res[i,...] = a[(*ix[i],)]
  return res

take_at(a, ix)
```

Comment: `a[ix]` doesn't work?

Comment: nop, a[ix] works like slices

Answer (score 1):

You need to pack `ix` into a tuple:

```
take_at(a, ix)
Out[]: array([ 6,  1, 21])

a[tuple(ix.T)]
Out[]: array([ 6,  1, 21])
```

Comment: is the tuple() iteration fast even if there are thousands of indices ? (since tuple is a python object I was wondering if it may get slow)

Comment: Fast as you can get in `python`, the indexing routines are compiled in `c` so it's much faster than iterating in `python` loops

Comment: I wait if another post a faster way, but I will mark it solve else

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
a[ix[:,0],ix[:,1],ix[:,2]]
```

Output:

```
array([ 6,  1, 21])
```

Comment: I need an arbitrary dynamic number of dimensions